# Почему объект не добавляется в массив?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Здравствуйте, подскажите почему после выполнения addrowtitle в массив order ничего не добавляется?

```
NSMutableArray *order;

@implementation OrderData

OrderData *oritem;

+ (void)addrowtitle :(NSString*)s price :(NSString*)p seat :(NSString*)n
{
    oritem = [[OrderData alloc] init];
    oritem.title=s;
    oritem.price=p;
    oritem.seat=n;
    [order addObject:oritem];
    NSLog(@"%@)%@-%@",oritem.seat,oritem.title,oritem.price);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятно потому что ваш массив не инициализирован.

Добавьте его инициализацию в начале метода.

```
+ (void)addrowtitle :(NSString*)s price :(NSString*)p seat :(NSString*)n
{
    if (order == nil) {
        order = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

UPD.

Но мне кажется и это не поможет, потому как переменная массива объявлена непонятно где и как.